# Update and Delete in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, crud

I want the user to only be able to do such actions as delete and update to their own posts (in this case comments).

I have two issues to address:

1. Multiple comments from different users show on the same page and I have the links to update or delete next to each comment. I only want the links to appear next to the comments if it is a comment they created.
2. I have already got the functionality to create, update and delete working (though update and delete doesn't currently take into account who the user is). I do not know if I need to implement Gates, Policies or both and how this will impact what I have already created... For example will I have have to move the code in my controller functions to a Policy? I have looked at Laravel resources which helped but I am still not clear.

Classes have relationships defined eg:

```
   class User extends Authenticatable
    {
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

I have functions to perform actions in my controller eg:

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',

    ]);

    $entry = new Comment();
    $film = Film::find($id);
    $entry->body = $request->body;
    $entry->film_id = $film->id;
    $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $entry->save();

    return redirect('/');
}


public function updateComment(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $entry = Comment::find($id);
    $entry->body = $request->body;
    $entry->save();
}
```

Comment table:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('film_id');
    $table->string('body');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Comments blade:

```
<h1>{{ $film->title }}</h1>

<!--<p>{{$film->comments}}</p>-->
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        @if (Auth::check())
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        @endif

@foreach ($film->comments as $comment)

    <tr>
        <td>{{$comment->body}}</td>
        <td>{{$comment->user['name']}}</td>

        @if (Auth::check())
        <td><a href="/update/{{$comment->id}}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="/delete/{{$comment->id}}">Delete</a></td>
        @endif
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@if (Auth::check())
<div>@include('form')</div>
@else
<h3>Please log in to add a comment</h3>
@endif
@endsection
```

Route example:

```
Route::get('/update/{id}', 'FilmsController@editComment')->name('editComment')->middleware('auth');
```

I am currently just using `@if (Auth::check())` to hide the links if not logged in but this is not a suitable solution for my problem.

Comment: Please post the relevant blade code too.

Comment: Just added blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the user id of the logged-in user with the user id of the current comment like `optional(Auth::user())->id === $comment->user_id`.

Mind the `optional()` here. This takes care that `Auth::user()` can return `null` in case no user is logged in. Without Laravel will throw an error because we calling `->id` on `null`.

Below I added this snipped into your code:

```
@foreach ($film->comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$comment->body}}</td>
        <td>{{$comment->user['name']}}</td>

        @if(optional(Auth::user())->id === $comment->user['id'])
        <td><a href="/update/{{$comment->id}}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="/delete/{{$comment->id}}">Delete</a></td>
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you @common sense. A slight change to this answer worked: `@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id === $comment->user['id'])`. At the same time if I exclude `Auth::check` and just do `@if(Auth::user()->id === $comment->user['id'])` this also works. Is is necessary to still have  `Auth::check`? Also even with `Auth::check` still there, I can alter the url and amend someone else's comment

Comment: You can remove the first check and should use `optional()` helper. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @common sense. My only issue now is that I can manually change url from say `commentupdate/1` to `commentupdate/2` and in doing so will be able to update a comment which does not belong to me. Not sure if this can maybe be addressed via route? I have added a route example to my post. I have used `->middleware('auth');` on necessary routes but wonder if there is a way to state specific user here?

Comment: UPDATE - Think I need middleware for this which I need to look into and will post a different question if needed. Thanks again @common sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "registered policy", you will be able to use "can" and "cant".  can/cant are work in blade as well as on the user.

$user->can('create', Post::class)

$user->can('update', $post_instance)

@can('update', $post_instance)
... and so on...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#registering-policies

Comment: I looked at this but as I said above I didn't understand how I can implement it in relation to existing code... For example I have function in controller to save, one to edit and another to delete a comment. And in the Policy documentation on laravel.com it says `class PostPolicy
{

    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }`How would this work in relation to my existing update function?